# How do I line up my textboxes without using a table? html/css

Tags: html, css

I want to display:

```
Name [Textbox]
Age: [Textbox]
BlahBlahCatfish: [Textbox]
```

but if I simply plonk the code in, it gets lined up exactly as its lined up above.

What I want is for it to be lined up like this:

```
Name:            [Textbox]
Age:             [Textbox]
BlahBlahCatfish: [Textbox]
```

Ordinarly I would use a Table but I am trying to get out of that habit and use lovely CSS. Ideas of how to do this without billions of divs and stuff?

Comment: For more complicated forms than this, especially in liquid layouts, you will generally still need to use tables. Don't worry too  much about it.

Comment: You don't ever *need* to use tables.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is a site I did that does that.

http://acm.cs.kent.edu/contact/form.php

Basically its like this

```
<p>
    <label for="someTextBox" >Text</label>
    <input type="text" id="someTextBox" />
</p>

p label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: x;
}
p input {
    width: y;
}
```

Comment: This is good: it preserves the semantics by introducing new tags.  Although using a class selector instead of the `p` would increase flexibility.

Comment: Fantastic. It never occured to me to use a <label>! Much appreciated.

Comment: Labels are best when used with the `for` attribute. It makes them clickable and gives the focus to the input field!

Comment: I think this works because the input fields are the same size. Different sizes = not lined up.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [960 Grid System](http://960.gs/) to handle form based layout, in particular I found the [Fluid 960 Grid System](http://www.designinfluences.com/fluid960gs/) most useful.

It's a simple and structured approach to layout, worth investing a little time to learn this as it will save you so much time in the future.

Another handy tool is the [Gridder](http://gridder.andreehansson.se/) bookmarklet to aide layout.

There are other CSS frameworks such as [Blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) which are equally as good.

Answer (score 0):

use a "left" and a "right" class, and make them `float:left` and `float:right`, respectively.  The text would then go in a `<div class="right">`, and the attribute name in a `<div class="left">`.